# How to modify jquery-token-input css to add a tiny rectangle around the X to cancel?

Tags: css, jquery-tokeninput

I am using the jQuery tokenInput plugin. My current tokens look like this:

[image]

If you look at the token fields, the latest tag called mstagtesting has an X at the end, which appears on mouse hover.

I want to change the area around the X and introduce a rectangle around the X to make it look like these if hovered on :
[image]

How do I modify the css to add the rectangle of white background color around the X that serves to de-select a token when clicked on ?
Thanks so much for your help and here is my css file:

```
/* Example tokeninput style #2: Mac Style */
fieldset.token-input-mac {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #A4BDEC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

fieldset.token-input-mac.token-input-dropdown-mac {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

ul.token-input-list-mac {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-height: 1px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

ul.token-input-list-mac.error {
  border: 1px solid #C52020;
}

ul.token-input-list-mac li {
list-style-type: none;
}

li.token-input-token-mac p {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li.token-input-token-mac span {
    color: #231C34;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* TOKENS */

li.token-input-token-mac {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto !important;
    font-size: 8pt;
    line-height: 12pt;
    margin: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    background: none;
    background-color: #0F004E;
    color: #fefefe;
    cursor: default;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.token-input-highlighted-token-mac {
    background-color: #231C34;
    color: #fefefe;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.token-input-selected-token-mac {
    background-color: #231C34;
    color: #fefefe;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

li.token-input-highlighted-token-mac span.token-input-delete-token-mac {
    color: #fefefe;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.token-input-selected-token-mac span.token-input-delete-token-mac {
    color: #fefefe;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.token-input-input-token-mac {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li.token-input-input-token-mac input {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: none;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac p {
    font-size: 8pt;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac h3.token-input-dropdown-category-mac {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-dropdown-item-mac span.token-input-dropdown-item-description-mac {
    float: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li strong {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac,
div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac.odd {
    background: #0F004E;
    color: #bb8322; //Official Red
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac:hover,
div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac.odd:hover,
div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac:focus,
div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac.odd:focus {
    color: #fff;
 }

div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac span.token-input-dropdown-item-description-mac,
 div.token-input-dropdown-mac ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-mac.odd span.token-input-dropdown-item-description-mac {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the "x"? is it an image that changes opacity? is it an image that changes display? Is it an ':after'? use the inspector in your browser t check that out. Make sure to post the code snippet of one tag including the "x". For this, you might need to right click on the element in the tree of the inspector and toggle "hover";

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/?hl=en

Comment: Can you also add the HTML? It depends on how the X is called in.